# Docker ps giving permission issues

Tags: docker

Issue for

```
http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution for this

Add the login user for ssh let's say gse to the docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker "gse"
```

then restart the vm using `sudo reboot`

and do `docker ps` and it works :-)

Comment: can we do without restarting the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with root user or add your user in docker group.